# Show a loading div once per visit, thereafter, a different loading div

Tags: jquery, session, session-cookies, splash-screen

Fairly new to Javascript and web developing in general, just looking for some help with the loading / transition DIVs I have on a site.

I use the jquery below to display an intro on the homepage and the same script on other pages (with a shorter fadeout and different div) to imitate a sort of transition. On the homepage I'd like to just show the intro div once per session or set period, however rather than displaying nothing between, I want to swap it for the other 'transition' div I use on other pages.

I looked at using cookies and session storage but not had any luck getting much to work specifically for this. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
$(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#splash').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        });
    },1200); 
});
```

**UPDATE**

After using the suggestion from @brad this is what I ended up using and works perfectly for what I was trying to achieve.

**HTML**

```
<div id="preloader">

     <div id="splash1">
     </div>

    <div id="splash2">
     </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#splashback {
display: none;
}

#splashback2 {
display: none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (sessionStorage.getItem('splash') !== 'true') {
         $( "#splash1" ).show();
         setTimeout(function(){
        $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        });
    },2500); 
    sessionStorage.setItem('splash','true');
}
else {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $( "#splash2" ).show();
        $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        });
    },500); 
}
```

});

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript.  As the saying goes, Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet.  And, you should really show us what you tried so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalStorage is the appropriate place for client-side-only variables you need to use.  It's also [very well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage).

To set a variable in local storage, just set it like so:

```
localStorage.yourVariable = "some value";
```

Note that all local storage variables are strings.  If you put some non-string value in, it will be converted to string.  Because of this, it's very common to read/write JSON with local storage.

```
localStorage.config = JSON.serialize({
  exampleSetting1: true,
  exampleSetting2: false
});
```

Then when you want to get the data back...

```
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.config));
```

Fortunately in  your case, type or anything doesn't matter.  You just need to set the variable to something.

```
localStorage.shownSplashScreen = true;
```

Then, to test whether or not you've shown the splash screen:

```
!!localStorage.shownSplashScreen;  // true if shown, false if not
```

Again, the value in `localStorage.shownSplashScreen` is a string with the value of `true`, not a boolean.  By using `!!`, we effectively cast to boolean, and detect whether or not that variable has a truthy value (which the string "true" is).

I'm mentioning all this so you can look some of these things up, if you aren't familiar with it.  The end solution is quite simple.  Untested but try this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#splash').fadeOut('slow');    
    }, (!!localStorage.shownSplashScreen) ? 0 : 1200); 
    localStorage.shownSplashScreen = true;
});
```

All we do here is set the splash screen time from `1200` ms if we haven't shown it, and `0` ms if we have (which will execute the function to hide it once this call stack is complete).

Comment: Thanks for listing all this! I tried your solution and it works although after showing initally, you still get about a 200ms flash of the #splash on return to the page. This may actually work as alternative but interested to see if I can somehow set it to serve a 'transition' div once the 'intro' div has been served. Also, would using session storage work with this? Looking for something that resets each visit or time period. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jord Yes, your splash screen will exist on the page until JavaScript can remove it.  If you don't want that, then your splash screen can't even be shown on the page at first.  That is, instead of hiding it with JavaScript when it's already been seen, show it with JavaScript when it hasn't been seen.  That sort of defeats the purpose of having a splash screen though, but you can make it work how you want.  As far as the timing, instead of putting `true` in that variable, just put a timestamp for when it was last shown.  Then, you can test for how long ago that timestamp was on load.

Comment: Ye I figured that was the case, wondered if it's placement makes any difference. I swapped local to session in the script and works pretty well as an alternative option for me so thanks for the help! Is it easy enough using another div once the initial div has been shown rather than removing the splash? So after showing #splash1, use #splash2 until end of session.

Comment: @Jord At this point, I'm not sure what it is you're trying to do, but yes, you can show/hide as you wish.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm looking to see if I can display a certain  splash (#intro) and once shown, show a different splash (#transition) on that page for the rest of the session? So you will see #intro the first time but #transition each time you go back to that page. Thanks

Comment: @Jord Yes, you can.  Have you tried it?  Did you have a specific question with your implementation?  From my answer above, you know how to read/write to/from localStorage, which should give you the information you need.

Comment: yes but as mentioned I'm new to Javascript so just still trying to figure it out a way to make the above idea work with the information you've given me. I'll test a few things and post anything I get working. Thanks again for your help!